# Path wildcard for Firebase Database iOS SDK

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in Firebase Functions, I can use

`ref.child("some/{wildcard}/path")`

and the returned event stores the wildcard's values at `events.params`.

I wonder if anything similar exists for Firebase Realtime Database's iOS SDk.

Comment: Did you ever manage to make this work on iOS?

Comment: No, it could be done in Firebase Functions. My question was exactly that, how can i do it on iOS?